# Saving data in android by using shared preferences - is it a good idea?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I am saving data of my application by using `SharedPreferences`. The data is somewhat simple and similar to db layout: user inputs 3 editFields, it is being stored and various statistics is calculated. Users can store some more data or delete it.

I talked about this with a professional android programmer and he said that it is not the best idea to save data by using `sharedPreferences` and that I should talk about this storage method "silently". I have been searching around stackOverflow, etc. for answers on how to correctly save data, and a lot of people are suggesting using `sharedPreferences`.

So this is my question: why is it a bad idea to save data by using `sharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well SharedPreferences are, as the name suggests, shared preferences and should not be used for user data (regardless of how insensitive it may be). Depending on how big the user input and how much data your planning to save, it's probably best to implement a SQL database.

**EDIT**: Also, use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings as these are small. (data which is like 'settings' in nature).

Answer (score 1):

If you have small amount or mainly static data, use SharedPreferences.

Otherwise, use a database like SQLite, wich will allow you to take advantage from sql language for searching your data.

Also, if you plan to have more than one user in your application, you would have to go for database.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences is a good way to store data that does not need to be secure. If users want, they (or possibly malicious apps) can edit shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what data you are trying to save. Check out the android documentation for guidance in using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Although the data might be simple now, you might want to use it a different way later. Using SQLLite etc will enable you to query the data and display results to the user.